# MVC5 cascading EditorFor in a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Given a controller method that returns an `IList<Scope>`
Where `Scope` contains a set of `bool` values, and some additional child objects.

```
public class Scope
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
    public Investment Item { get; set; }
}
```

I have a main view with the following markup:

```
@model IList<Scope>
<div>
    @Html.EditorForModel("Panel")
</div>
```

I have a view called `Panel.cshtml` inside EditorTemplates structured like this:

```
@model IList<Scope>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
{
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <p>@Model[i].Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Html.EditorFor(_ => _[i])
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The `EditorFor(_ => _[i])` doesn't render the standard object template with and editor for each of the fields based on its type?

Why does `EditorFor` not render an editor for each of the properties when it is called from inside another editor?

If I move all the markup from the `Panel.cshtml` into the master view, it works correctly.
Is it not possible to get the same behavior from an editor template?

Comment: Just curious, what does `@Html.EditorFor(_ => _[i])` do? Should I ask this as a full question?

Comment: Its the same as HTML.EditorFor(model => model[i]). In functional programming (prolog,f#,Haskell etc) the underscore is used instead of a full variable name when the context makes it unambiguous. I use the same terse notation in C# lambdas, in my opinion it's better than writing x everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate `EditorFor` for each property of model:

```
@model IList<Scope>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
{
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <p>@Model[i].Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Html.EditorFor(_ => Model[i].A)
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Html.EditorFor(_ => Model[i].B)
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
}
```

or if you don't want iterate `EditorFor` for each property of model try this:

```
@foreach (var scope in Model)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => scope);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid the scenario where I have to hand code each property. I ideally want the default object editor to be used so that I don't have to code each property.

Comment: Hi, that's what I need, only it doesn't work. If I put the foreach in Panel.cshtml each of the items in the for loop is rendered as a zero '0' on the page. The default object editor (Object.ascx) is not called for each of the items in the foreach.